# Replacing value inside VueJs Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have two arrays that are:

1) `listArray` and it's formatted like this:

```
0: {value: "373", text: "1 - First Item in the Array"}
1: {value: "343", text: "2 - Second Item in the Array"}
2: {value: "376", text: "3 - Third Item in the Array"}
```

2) `displayArray` and it's formatted like this:

```
0: {name: "Number One", position: "373", additionalinfo: "Description Goes Here"}
1: {name: "Number Two", position: "343", additionalinfo: "Description Goes Here"}
2: {name: "Number three", position: "376", additionalinfo: "Description Goes Here"}
```

I would like to have the second array `displayArray` use information from `listArray` to look like this:

```
0: {name: "Number One", position: "1 - First Item in the Array", additionalinfo: "Description Goes Here"}
1: {name: "Number Two", position: "2 - Second Item in the Array", additionalinfo: "Description Goes Here"}
2: {name: "Number three", position: "3 - Third Item in the Array", additionalinfo: "Description Goes Here"}
```

I don't mind creating a third array, but when I tried to use it inside `array.push`, I got errors.  How can I do that?

Comment: What have you tried and what errors did you get? A `forEach` or `map` should do it.

Comment: how would that be a conditional getting data from array 1 and replace array 2?

Comment: it's not an error, but rather it didn't work by replacing the position value from array 2 with the text value from array 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: Change `displayArray`

Use `forEach`:

```js
displayArray.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.position = listArray[index].text;
})
```

## Option 2: Create a new array

Use `map`:

```js
const newArray = displayArray.map((item, index) => {
  const newitem = Object.assign({}, item);
  newitem.position = listArray[index].text;
  return newitem;
})
```

Here is a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/1smcf9o8/)